# Console log a name depending of the result of a calculation in javascript

Tags: if-statement, console.log

hi i am new here and i am codding a litttle program to calculate the price by unit of a product depend on his quantitie and price (the product coming in 12pcs, 18pcs and 20pcs)and i want to console log wichone is the one have the minimun price if is the 12 console log dozen if is the minimun, eighteen the same etc.
I be able to console log the minimun price(the number) with Math.min but i dont know who belongs to if is from 12pcs,18pcs or 20pcs
Sorry if my english is not good its my second language

```
var docena="12";
var dieciocho="18";
var veinte="20";
var precio_docena=prompt("precio docena");
var precio_dieciocho=prompt("precio dieciocho");
var precio_veinte=prompt("precio veinte");
var precio_unidad12=precio_docena/docena;
var precio_unidad18=precio_dieciocho/dieciocho;
var precio_unidad20=precio_veinte/veinte;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi Fernando will you please share some more of your code, please

you can achieve this by using if-condition
like

```js
var docena="12";
var dieciocho="18";
var veinte="20";
var precio_docena=prompt("precio docena");
var precio_dieciocho=prompt("precio dieciocho");
var precio_veinte=prompt("precio veinte");
var precio_unidad12=precio_docena/docena;
var precio_unidad18=precio_dieciocho/dieciocho;
var precio_unidad20=precio_veinte/veinte;
if(docena<dieciocho && docena<veinte){
  console.log('dozen docena')
}
else if(dieciocho<docena && dieciocho<veinte){
console.log('dieciocho ',dieciocho)
}
else{
console.log('veinte ',veinte)
}
```

you can update if-condition as per you need

Comment: Thanks thats what i need and i try that but i wrotte wrong the if\else statement and yours are the right thanks

Comment: Its working my fail when o was writting the if else statement was writting in the console.log the name i want to output without the part belong to